# How to disable splash screen in ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic2, splash-screen

I have changed the value to none for splash screen in the config.xml. So Splash screen is not showing up. But the white screen is showing up. Is there away to avoid that white screen?

this is my config.xml file:

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0"/> 
<preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="false"/> 
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="none"/>
```

Comment: What would you like users to see instead of the splash screen and the white screen?
Note: that the white screen is actually the webview (browser) still loading files and rendering the page.

Comment: I have created an animated splash screen. It works perfectly. So i have disabled the default splash screen. Default splash is not showing up. But the white screen showing up Before animated splash screen. So i want to hide that white screen. Is there a way to hide?

Comment: I think the white screen is showing because the internal browser is starting and loading the assets. So, to my knowledge, I don't expect it to be possible to completely avoid it.

Comment: You can try by setting that animation as the background of the `ion-app` element. Is just an idea, but I was able to change the color with this style rule in the `app.scss` file: `ion-app.md.platform-cordova.platform-mobile,
ion-app.ios.platform-cordova.platform-mobile { ... }`

Comment: i have placed my code in index.html. But Still, It shows a white screen.

Answer (score 1):

As said above, your app needs time to load the assets and render, so you will unfortunately always have that white screen if you just remove the splash.

I would suggest that in config.xml you keep the splashcreen but that you only replace the default splashcreen resource inside the respective platform. For instance, it would looks like below, with your resources referenced from the root folder of your project:

```
 <platform name="android">
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
 </platform>
 <platform name="ios">
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" height="2048"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" height="2732"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" height="1024"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>
 </platform>
```

I have never worked with animated splashscreens however and don't know if it will work.

Comment: Actually,  I have designed an animated splash screen with HTML and CSS. It works perfectly. I have removed default splash. But a white screen shows for 5 sec before an animated splash screen shows up. How to fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot. Your hybrid app must load first, before you can make use of any HTML/CSS design.

Comment: Oh..Okay. Thank you