# How to remove splash screen from ionic 2 app?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have designed the app using ionic 2. I don't want a splash screen in my app. So, How to remove it?

Comment: Yes i removed it. splash screen is not shown up but white screen is showing up now. How to fix it?

Comment: @ sagar. I have removed the splash screen in my app. Then i have added this line.                     <preference name="SplashScreen" value="none"/>. Splash screen is not shown up. But white screen is showing up now. How to fix it?

Comment: are you sure the "white screen" is not your angular app that is loading..?

Comment: Come on, close this question, this is crazy ! Plus he already asked the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42805109/how-to-disable-splash-screen-in-ionic-2

Answer (score 9):

According to last version of ionic 2:

1. remove plugin `ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-splashscreen`
2. remove npm package `npm uninstall --save @ionic-native/splash-screen`
3. remove preferences about splashScreen in config.xml
4. add this line to your config.xml `<preference name="SplashScreen" value="none"/>`
5. remove splashScreen from app.module.ts "import and providers"
6. remove splashScreen from app.component.ts

Comment: Yeah I did same thing. Splash screen is not shown up. But white screen is showing up now. Could you suggest me how to fix it?

Comment: Check your console on browser and console see if you got any error.`ionic serve -c`

Comment: No. I din't get any error in console.

Comment: Try to build it.`ionic run android/ios -device` and see  if you got any error.

Comment: I did. No error. White screen is showing up.

Comment: In chrome check if pages loading in your html or not. also check network tab.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139840/discussion-between-ard-and-amin-arghavani).

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer, because this fixed it for me.